# utility to dump memory representation of float?

Tags: c, endianness

I'm looking for a utility that'll dump how a various number types are stored in RAM. It's easy to write but if there is a ready tool for achieving this, it'll be great.

Hopefully it'll take of endianess as well.

Syntax could be something like this:

```
hex uint32 big
```

E.g.

```
hex float big 0.012
```

will show

```
0xa6 0x9b 0x44 0x3c
```

or in a complete reversed order :-)

EDIT: I'm looking for a universal tool and hopefully CLI based. debugger doesn't handle endianess.

Thanks,

Comment: A debugger jumps to mind.  Or the IEEE-754 spec.  Or a simple cast: dumpBytes((unsigned char*)&floatValue, sizeof(floatValue));

Comment: You can use the `"%a"` or `"%A"` printf conversion specifier for `double`s

Comment: How do you expect to "dump how *types* are stored"? That's something that takes a document with a spec (and not a small one in general case). One can easily dump how a particular *value* of some specific type is stored, but the example you gave does not seem to support that. So, once again, what is meant by "dump how *types* are stored"??? A manpage? Or a hexdump? If the latter, then where's the specific value you want to dump? (And what's `big`? Endianness?)

Comment: I think you misunderstand my question.  There is no `uint32` type in standard C.

Comment: @pmg: `%a` just prints a representation of a double *value*.

Comment: @Keith: I thought maybe the OP could use it as poor man's "ready tool" :-)

Comment: @pmg: Sure, it doesn't actually answer the question (which I suppose is why it was a comment), but it might be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio has the option to look directly into memory. While debugging, go to Debug -> Windows -> Memory. You can then paste the address of the variables you want to inspect and see the bits.